# Error 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal' in asyncpg

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

My queries were giving strange results so i debugged a little bit, i change my `String`, date object to sqlalchemy `Date` so it raised this error

```
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $2: '2020-03-11'
('str' object has no attribute 'toordinal')
```

Here is my sqlalchemyTable

```
db = sqlalchemy.Table(
"db",
metadata,
sqlalchemy.Column("date", Date),
sqlalchemy.Column("data", JSONB),
)
```

how i insert values:

```
query = db.insert().values(
    date=datetime.strptime(key,"%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    data=value,
)
try:
    await database.execute(query)
except UniqueViolationError:
    pass
```

Why did i change the type String to Date,because when i ran a query like

```
query = f"""SELECT * FROM db WHERE date BETWEEN SYMMETRIC '{start_at}' AND '{end_at}'"""
return await database.execute(query)
```

It was only returning one row and one column like `2020-03-11`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say your issue is here:

`date=datetime.strptime(key,"%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),`

You are passing a string to a date field.  SQLAlchemy is looking for a date object to be passed in, hence the `('str' object has no attribute 'toordinal')` error. toordinal being an attribute of a date object. Remove the `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` and it should work.

Comment: Hello again @Adrian yup i'm aware of that but i need to store as yyyy-mm-dd format how could i achieve that?

Comment: If you are storing in a date field in the database it won't be stored in a format. It is stored as a numerical value relative to the epoch. Formatting is something you do on retrieval.  If you are not storing in a date field in the database then you should not be using Date in your model.